# Passing an element into a javascript function which is then added to EventListener

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write a small javascript to validate the input of type = "number" in the form of my website. Basically, this function is trying to make sure the maximum length of input allowed is no longer than the arguments I have passed in. I wrote the function to take in two arguments, one is an html element and the other is the maxlength. However, after I add this function to the input element, it does not seem to be working. Please take a look and tell me where I have gone wrong and what concepts I missed.

```
/* Show submit button only when the form has been validated */
/* Variables */
var form = document.querySelector(".resForm");
var resFormBtn = document.querySelector(".submitButton");
var numInput = document.querySelector("#numberInput");

function showSubmitButton() {
    if (form.checkValidity() === true) {
        resFormBtn.style.display = "block";
    }
}

function validateNumInput(maxlength, ele) {
    if (ele.length > maxlength) {
        ele.value = ele.value.slice(0, maxlength);
    }
}

form.addEventListener("change", showSubmitButton, false);

numInput.addEventListener("input", function () {
    validateNumInput(8, numInput);
}, false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (ele.length > maxlength)
```

There is something wrong here. ele is a referenced node, it has no such a property called "length", therefore the code inside the condition will never trigger.

simply change it to

```
ele.value.length > maxlength
```

the code will just do fine

Comment: OMG, you saved my day. Can't believe how stupid I was

Comment: Hi, because I am still new to javascript, why this way, it won't work? numInput.addEventListener("input",validateNumInput(8,numInput),false);

Comment: @Anlinyang addEventListener takes a function as parameter but if you past a function expression(in your case the function invoke immediately) then the parameter became undefined